# Powershell 2.0 - Remove Group Membership for List of Disabled Accounts

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, activedirectorymembership, group-membership

I'm trying to remove AD group membership for a list of users whose accounts have been disabled but not sure how to properly combine the cmdlets.  This is my attempt...

```
Import-CSV T:\temp\users.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.member | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.member -MemberOf SamAccountName}}
```

users.csv (file contents below)

```
member
testuser1
testuser2
testuser3
```

I get the following message...

```
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to
the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not s
upported.
At line:1 char:160
+ Import-CSV T:\temp\users.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.member | ForEach-Object {R
emove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity <<<<  $_.member -MemberOf SamAccountName}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADPrincipalGro
   upMembership
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to also provide a sample of the data you're operating on (in this case, what the contents of **users.csv** looks like), since the key to resolving the problem could lie in the data you're reading in. However, in this case I believe I can see what's tripping you up without seeing the data.

Keep in mind that in each stage of the pipeline, **$_** is set the the values of each of the objects from the previous stage of the pipeline. **$_.member** doesn't have a consistent value throughout the pipeline.

In the second stage, `ForEach-Object {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.member`, **$_.member** evaluates to the values of the "member" column of the CSV file. In the third stage, `ForEach-Object {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.member -MemberOf SamAccountName}`, it evaluates to the **Member** property of the group objects passed from the second stage. Those objects don't have a **Member** property, so **$_.member** is null.

What you can do is capture the values from the CSV file (usernames, I presume?) it into a variable at the beginning of the first **ForEach-Object** filter, and use that as the **-Identity** argument:

```
Import-Csv T:\temp\users.csv | %{
  $user = $_.member
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user | %{
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_.SamAccountName
  }
}
```

Also, note that the argument to **-MemberOf** should be **$_.SamAccountName**. In PowerShell 3.0, the following *will* give you the **SamAccountName** property of each group:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user | % SamAccountName
```

However, in a scriptblock you need **$_.SamAccountName**. In PowerShell 2.0 (as you've tagged this question), you can't use bare property names at all.

Comment: Updated post above with users.csv for others' reference if looking for same solution.  Thanks, Adi Inbar

Comment: @user2731132 Whenever your questions are answered at StackOverflow, rather than posting comments thanking the answerer (which often end up getting deleted by mods), please mark the answer that best resolved the question as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer: meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Also, you gain +2 rep when you accept an answer. ;)

Comment: Ok thanks.  Was looking for button to accept answer.  Clicking the check mark is certainly much easier.  Still learning to navigate the site.